# Display Google calender in Laravel application

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api, laravel-7

I am trying to display Google Calendar in Laravel application. I can fetch Google Calender using [this](https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/laravel-google-calendar) package.

[image]

How can I display **Calendar** like below ?

[image]

Thanks @Prisoner. I used below code in my controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Spatie\GoogleCalendar\Event;

use Calendar;

class HomeController extends BaseController
{
    public function calendar() {
        $events = [];
        $data = Event::get();

        if($data->count()){
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $events[] = Calendar::event(
                    $value->name,
                    true,
                    new \DateTime($value->startDate),
                    new \DateTime($value->endDate.' +1 day')
                );
            }
        }
        $calendar = Calendar::addEvents($events);
        return view('welcome', compact('calendar'));
    }
}
```

But I am getting White screen.

Comment: The google calendar API just returns the raw json data to you.  Formatting it will be up to you have you tried?

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo. I need the Formatting. Yes, I tried but failed. Could you please help me in this regard ?

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo. Sorry, I couldn't understand.

Comment: You need to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo. Could you please guide me in this regard ? Do you have any tutorial ? Thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow works best when you have a problem that you can demonstrate that needs to be solved, or something that you've attempted, and you can show how you've attempted it, but that still isn't working. You've indicated that you "tried but failed" - showing what you've tried and illustrating how it fails will make it far easier for us to help you get it working.

Comment: Thanks @Prisoner. I updated my Question for you. Please check it. Thanks.

Comment: If you get a completely white screen then it may indicate that PHP has crashed. Have you got error logging enabled, and have you checked the PHP error log file?